# Multi MFRC522 Slave AND only mifare read

Tags: rfid

Multiple MFRC522 Connections (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi)
I only get from each slave with an ID card; I want to print a defined barcode on the slave address. Briefly; The MOSI line does not matter! Is the 2nd case daisy chain method in this link suitable for me? would like to ask you, dear friends, how should I go about it?
<Regards[image]

Comment: what is `ID card`?

Comment: There is only one daisy chained example shown in the article. ;-) Do you know, that the slaves that are chained, must be able to transport the incomming (MOSI) data to the outgoing port (MISO). This is not the case for all slave devices. I do not think the MFRC522 allows this mode. Why not use the multi slave setup from the example before the daisy chain example? Then you will also be able to select the slave you want to read from.

Comment: Tomorrow, I will install 7 mfrc522.  SS pin (SDA) will not be enough.  Is it necessary to use the 74HC238?  I guess I should also connect pull-up (10k) to SDA and SCK wires .. I read the problem of impedance .. I will have a particular question;  Where do I get the name or code of the slave device.  Thanks for your answer

Comment: evet. geç oldu cevabım özür dilerim. Normal Seçici SS leri ayrı ayrı kullanarak sorunu çözdüm. Burada max. kaç adet bağlanır bilmiyorum. Ama; 5 adet şimdilik işimi görür gibi.